# Problem in Tensor calculation

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm a theoretical physics M.SC. student, I have some problems in extending a tensor. Can anyone open up this tensor? it will be a great help for me. And also I want to know what is the difference between the first and last term in this tensor?  Does it make a difference to change the order of the upper index and lower index?
$$T_{ab}=\nabla_c[J^{c}{}_{(a} u_{b)} +u^c J_{(ab)}- J_{(a}{}^{c} u_{b)}]\tag{7}.$$
It is equation (12) in the following paper:
DOI: https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/23/18/009 ([version on Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604088)).

Comment: the notation is clunky, could you recheck?(something here)_{ blah blah} for getting stuff down in subscript

Comment: Yes the order does make a difference in general if the tensor isn't symmetric over those indices.

Comment: I dont know why I can't write the correct notation! I think maybe it is because of parenthesis.

Comment: So what's the decomposition of RHS??

Comment: I fixed the indices (take a look to see the way to do it) and also the equation number I think you mean is (12). But see my answer below for the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first term in equation (12) of the paper linked (which I assume is the equation you're referring to) is $$
\nabla_m \big( J_{(a}{}^m u_{b)} - J^{m}{}_{(a} u_{b)} - J_{(ab)} u^{m} \big) \, ,
$$
and your question appears to be why $ J_{(a}{}^m u_{b)} \neq J^{m}{}_{(a} u_{b)}$. Explicitly, these terms are $\frac{1}{2}\big(J_{a}{}^{m}u_b + J_{b}{}^{m}u_a - J^{m}{}_{a} u_{b} -  J^{m}{}_{b} u_{a} \big)$. It should be obvious that $J_{a}{}^{m} \neq J^{m}{}_a$ if $J$ is not symmetric, because this is just $g^{ab} J_{am} \neq g^{ab} J_{ma}$ which follows from $J_{am} \neq J_{ma}$.

Alternatively, look at the definition of $J^a{}_m$ in the paper (which is Eq. (11), but you'll also need the definition of $K$ in Eq. (5)) and go through the details of why $J$ isn't symmetric.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps me a lot. It literally solved my problem.

Comment: @AminAghababaie Welcome! You could accept the answer if that's all.